# reading a txt file separated by commas into arrays C++ cpp

Tags: c++, csv

C++ question!

I have a .txt file with this info:

```
james, watson
brittany,blake
roger,tra4@pos
jonathan, pote5
amber,Trisa123!
```

where the first column is name and the second one is the Id of website users.

I need to read this file and then store the information into 2 arrays:

```
name[]
user_Id []
```

Could you please help me? I found the solution for saving it into a 2d vector but I prefer to save it as arrays since I need to compare the string values with another string (received by user to check if her name/user Id is already in the system or not)

I found the solution for saving it into a 2d vector but not for arrays.

Comment: ***I found the solution for saving it into a 2d vector but not for arrays.*** It shouldn't be that different to use std::array<> instead of std::vector<>. You will have to add additional checks in the std::array<> case so that you don't go out of bounds since an array in standard `c++` is fixed size at compile time.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read CSV comma separated values 2d vector".  There are already a plethora of examples on the internet.  Always search first before posting.

Comment: Rows and columns in a text file don't exist when you read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you your requested solution, but I am sorry to inform you that the solution approach is wrong. For various reasons. First, and most important: In C++ C-Style arrays should in general **not** not be used.

C-Style arrays have fixed size and are not dyanmic. So, you will always come up with a magic number of an *estimated* max size. The correct approach would be to use a dynamic container. And for your solution, the `std::vector` is most appropriate.

Then, it is a very bad idea to have to separate arrays for related data. The correct approach is to put related data in a `struct` and then create a `std::vector` of this struct. Otherwise you will have always to maintain and handle always 2 arrays, and you may even lose the sync between related data.

Anyway, I will first show you a solution following your idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int MagicNumberForMaxArraySize = 42;

int main() {

    // Define Arrays to hold the user and their IDs
    string user[MagicNumberForMaxArraySize]{};
    string user_ID[MagicNumberForMaxArraySize]{};

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    if (ifs.is_open()) {

        unsigned int index = 0;
        // Read all lines and put result into arrays
        while ((index < MagicNumberForMaxArraySize) and 
            (getline(getline(ifs, user[index], ',') >> ws, user_ID[index]))) {
            // Now we have read a comlete line. Goto next index
            ++index;
        }
        // Show debug output
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            cout << "User: " << user[i] << "\tID: " << user_ID[i] << '\n';
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

But I would not recommend to go on with that. The next improvement would be to use a `struct` and then an array of struct. Additionaly, I will get rid of `using namespace std;` which should never be used. And, I initialize varaibles with the universal initializer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


const unsigned int MagicNumberForMaxArraySize = 42;

struct Data {
    std::string user{};
    std::string ID{};
};

int main() {

    // Define array for our needed data
    Data data[MagicNumberForMaxArraySize];

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    if (ifs.is_open()) {

        unsigned int index = 0;
        // Read all lines and put result into arrays
        while ((index < MagicNumberForMaxArraySize) and 
            (std::getline(std::getline(ifs, data[index].user, ',') >> std::ws, data[index].ID))) {
            // Now we have read a comlete line. Goto next index
            ++index;
        }
        // Show debug output
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            std::cout << "User: " << data[i].user << "\tID: " << data[i].ID<< '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

Evolution:

We will now introduce an object oriented principle . Data and methods operating on this data shall be in one `class` or `struct`. Hence, we will add IO methods to the `struct`, and add an aditional `struct` for holding all users. Also, the new `if`-statement with initializer can be used. And of course the `std::vector`.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

// Struct to hold properties for one user
struct User {
    std::string name{};
    std::string ID{};

    // Simple extraction
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, User& user) {
        std::getline(std::getline(is, user.name, ',') >> std::ws, user.ID);
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const User& user) {
        return os << "User: " << user.name << "\tID: " << user.ID;
    }
};
// This class will contain all users
struct Data {
    std::vector<User> users{};
    // Simple extraction
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Data& d) {
        // Delete potential existing old data
        d.users.clear();
        // Now read all users
        for (User temp{}; is >> temp; d.users.push_back(std::move(temp)));
        return is;
    }
    // Simple inserter
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Data& d) {
        for (const User& u : d.users) os << u << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");ifs) {

        // Read all data and show result
        if (Data data{}; not (ifs >> data).bad())
            std::cout << data;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response! it solved my problem completely.

Comment: Hi there! first of all, thanks so much for the solution. very informative and in one word awsome! however I have a follow up question. As I said before I need to get user and user Id from the user and compare it with the database. so I get a string from the user/userId  with cin, and then compare it with the user/userid that I have extracted from the txt file. it wirks comeletly fine for user but for userId whenever I input the same text it doesnt match with the database! could you tell me why is that happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Id is a string that could be "*Xvm2xmyq3" . I print it out and it shows the correct "Xvm2xmyq3". But when I do string compare, with the exact same "Xvm2xmyq3", it doent rescgnize them as same! (no problem with names (first column) with any value though) I think the problem does not come from the format since I have this problem for all of the strings that have been stores in ID (second column). Could it be because it stores an extra character when the line ends?

Comment: I printed the size of ID words written from the txt file. all the Id data has one size more than the actual size (except for the last row). however when I print it I dont see an extra character!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strtok()` from `cstring` library to split string into tokens: [Split string in C/C++](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)